# Why is JavaScript embedded in a PDF opened with Firefox not executed?

Tags: firefox, pdf, javascript

I have embedded a simple JavaScript (app.alert messagebox) in a PDF using [Didier Stevens pdf-tools](http://blog.didierstevens.com/programs/pdf-tools/).

Then I open that PDF in Firefox in Linux and the Javascript is not executed. The messagebox is not shown.

If I open the same PDF in Windows the Javascript is executed correctly and the messagebox is shown.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not really expert about this, but just for check, make sure you did not disabled javascript into firefox linux, by open inspector (ctrl+shift+i) > settings (gear icon) > Advanced settings ~ checkbox Disable javascript

Comment: @lese I have checked and Javascript is NOT disabled.

Comment: as additional check, just to decrease the range of possibilities, http://www.javatester.org/javascript.html

Comment: @ago Your test page is returning "JavaScript IS WORKING in your web browser"

Comment: this post contain some information, search in page for 'firefox' occurrences  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205180/how-to-print-a-pdf-from-the-browser

Comment: If the Firefox PDF viewer is used, this is no surprise, because the Firefox PDF viewer does not understand (Acrobat) JavaScript. On the Windows side, it is very likely that Acrobat/Reader is installed, and provides the PDF viewing component for Firefox. And, of course, Acrobat/Reader understands (Acrobat) JavaScript.

Comment: @ago: We are not talking about web browser JavaScript here, we are talking about Acrobat JavaScript. That testing page tests for web browser JavaScript